# Multiple webcams in Actionscript 3 on OS X?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I am developing an AS3 AIR application which aims to use multiple webcams, i have two logitech c615 hooked up on the usb ports, i can get one of the video streams, but i can't seem to be able to access the other cam video,

Problem is I just get video from one of the usb webcams, usually the last one i connected.

the code i use is:

```
webcam = Camera.getCamera("0");

webcamVideo = new Video();
webcamVideo.width = 320;
webcamVideo.height = 240;
webcamVideo.x = 18;
webcamVideo.y = 329;

webcamVideo.attachCamera(webcam);
addChild(webcamVideo);

webcam2 = Camera.getCamera("1");

webcamVideo2 = new Video();
webcamVideo2.width = 320;
webcamVideo2.height = 240;
webcamVideo2.x = 158;
webcamVideo2.y = 29;

webcamVideo2.attachCamera(webcam2);
addChild(webcamVideo2);

var names:Array = Camera.names;
trace("Cam names:" + Camera.names.length);
```

but i never get the other cameras, is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From my experience on OS X, I could only get Flash to recognize multiple webcams if they had different names. With four identical Logitech cameras and my iSight, I could only use one of the Logitech at once (no issues with the iSight)

I know it's possible for an application to view them all (EvoCam does it somehow), but I had the exact same results with Flash as when using the QTCapture APIs in a native application I whipped up. The QTCapture API or the Logitech driver is probably bugged in this regard.